# How to save information in text document

Tags: discord.py

I am new to making discord bots, i was wondering how to save the information in a text document.
I found the code online and it works fine, i just want to know if its possible to save the output to a text document.

```
import discord
import os
import sys

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.presences = True
intents.members = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    for guild in client.guilds:
            for member in guild.members:
                    print(member)
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a build-in python module called [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html)

here is an example

```py
import discord
import os
import sys
import logging

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.presences = True
intents.members = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

# ----------------------- the logger -----------------------
logging.basicConfig(filename='log.txt', filemode='a', format='%(asctime)s %(msecs)d- %(process)d -%(levelname)s - %(message)s', datefmt='%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S %p', level=logging.INFO)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    for guild in client.guilds:
            for member in guild.members:
                    print(member)
```

it will save every output with INFO level into a file called log.txt

all logging level listed [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging-levels)

Comment: Thanks i will try it